# I cannot click on the on screen keyboard using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use sendkeys to send keystrokes to a Remote Terminal Application.

This does not work.

After some investigation it became apparent that this has been a fairly common issue.

I found that someone had posted that they were using the on screen keyboard to simulate clicks and successfully passing the keystrokes to the remote machine.

This would work great for me but I cannot get the on screen keyboard to recognize the click.

Here is some code I have to just try and use the on screen keyboard to enter the number 4 into a cell in excel.

The code moves to cell A1 and clicks it, then moves to the number 4 on the osk but no click as far as I can tell.

Thanks for your help

```
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long,ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cbuttons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Integer = 2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = 4

Private Type pointapi
    x  As Long
    y  As Long
End Type

Sub test()

    ' Cursor Position 61, 206 is cell A1 on the excel sheet

    SetCursorPos 61, 206
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'click left mouse
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'release left mouse

    ' Cursor Position 255, 937 is the number 4 on the on screen keyboard

    SetCursorPos 255, 937
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'click left mouse
    Call mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0) 'release left mouse

End Sub
```

Comment: try adding a `sleep(50)` or a doevents or any kind of delay after positioning

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried several variations of sleep and doevents to no avail. I tried clicking on the calculator and it works like a charm, it seems like the on screen keyboard is blocking the automated click somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to type something use "sendkeys"

```
SendKeys "%fa~" 'works like Alt+f then Alt+a (File>Save As)
Sleep 500
SendKeys "Hurrah_" 'on the text field
Sleep 500
```